# Python - \n interfering

Tags: python

Hopefully a quick for for this one. I have a script replacing a specific value with a file location. The location unfortunetly seems to quite often contain \n or n\ in (it because the current directory is in the temp folders), causing the line to either break or remove itself from the line entirely making the folder location invalid.

The temp dir usually looks something like this.

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\nsfCDAC.tmp\Firefox
```

Is there a way to prevent \n or n\ from executing? Any help is appreciated, and here's what my line replacement script looks like. Thanks in advance!

```
      #Editing Prefs.fs
        def replaceAll(file,searchExp,replaceExp):
            for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=1):
                if searchExp in line:
                    line = line.replace(searchExp,replaceExp)
                sys.stdout.write(line)

        replaceAll(rootDir + "/Firefox/Data/prefs.js",'FirefoxAppDirHere',rootDir + "\\FirefoxApp.exe")
```

**EDIT:**

eryksun method that he commented with on this post worked perfectly for me! Thanks a lot! I'd mark the question as solved but you must make a post first.

Comment: Should this be platform specific? If so, checkout [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html), especially `os.sep`.

Comment: If you're saving a string to prefs.js, you should escape any backslashes it contains: `replace('\\', '\\\\')`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are specifying the directory name within your script, you should use a raw string literal by prefixing the literal with `r`. For example, `r"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\nsfCDAC.tmp\Firefox"`. This will keep the backslashes from being interpreted.

Comment: How would I place it in this sense? As the string starts with rootDir + "\\FirefoxApp.exe" and not a " at the beginning. Is there something I can wrap it with like str("Whatever")?

Answer (score 2):

Your string in memory has plain backslash characters. It's not a problem of accidentally creating control characters such as line feed on the Python side. But if you're writing this out to a Javascript program, then you have to escape the backslashes. For example:

```
>>> x = r"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\nsfCDAC.tmp"

>>> print(x)
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\nsfCDAC.tmp
```

So in memory this string has single backslash characters. Let's try to compile and evaluate it as a string:

```
>>> print(eval("'%s'" % x))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in 
position 2-4: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

To fix this you can replace each backslash with two backslashes:

```
>>> x = x.replace('\\', '\\\\')

>>> print(x)
C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\nsfCDAC.tmp

>>> print(eval("'%s'" % x))
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\nsfCDAC.tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

Michael Hoffman's solution is good in general, if for any reason you need the string not to be raw, you can also add an extra backslash:

```
"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\\nsfCDAC.tmp"
```

The extra backslash keeps the \n (or any other special function like that) from running. For example (I believe, I'm running off of vague recollection here), if you need a string with ' and " in it, you can do:

```
"blah blah blah, he said \"hi!\", and continued on, \'til he got to the road. Blah blah!"
```

Comment: The idea is good, but the I can't alter rootDir as it's set by the system depending on where the application is running from. (In this case, the randomly named and generated temp folder)

Answer (score 0):

you should use a raw string literal by prefixing the literal with **r**. For more details about raw strings

[you can visit here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/strings.html) or [other link is here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65211-convert-a-string-into-a-raw-string/)